# Android how to make my app not visible for devices with resolution smaller than 480x800

Tags: java, android, manifest, resolution

Hello I'm developing a game with resolution 480x800 or bigger.I don't want my game be able to download and seen from google play from devices which have resolution smaller than 480x800.
How can I do this here is my manifest ,I'm not sure will this code solve the problem :

```xml
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:resizeable="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

<compatible-screens>
     <!-- no small screens -->

     <!-- screens which are 480x800 or bigger resolution -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi"></screen>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/><screen />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"></screen>

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi"></screen>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
   <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />


</compatible-screens>
```

Will this code hide my application in google play for devices which have resolution smaller than 480x800?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the developer's console, under your app click the button that opens the menu (next to your app) and click "APK", on there you can see "All supported devices" and "Excluded Devices" just go to supported devices and pick manually the ones you don't want (and they go to the "excluded devices" section).

Although I suggest to just "resize" the game for smaller screens, at most cases it's going to be better!

Comment: I can't resize my game because I'm developing it with AndEngine and I set camera_width to 800 and camera_height to 480,but this is good idea I'll try when I upload the game thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

With DisplayMetrics you can find the dimensions of the actual device in pixels; use them wisely.
See the Android documentation for more information on how to use it.

Comment: I'm developing the game with AndEngine and I set camera_width to 800 and camera_height to 480.The game looks so good on devices with resolution 480x800 or bigger,but I would want to make the game not visible and not able to download from devices which have resolution smaller than 480x800.And I wonder how to do that

Comment: He's looking for an answer that hides the app from the play store; his app can only access DisplayMetrics after it's been downloaded and is running.